# OutOfMemory Exception in Video File Uploading to server android

Tags: android

Before posting this questions i have searched a lot in stack overflow but couldn't find the solution..some of them are ..

[How to Upload Large Video FIle on server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26158922/how-to-upload-large-video-file-on-server)

[video upload in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15523884/video-upload-in-android)

[Upload large file in Android without outofmemory error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630430/upload-large-file-in-android-without-outofmemory-error)

[Upload files by post to server OutOfMemory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19647319/upload-files-by-post-to-server-outofmemory)

[Upload file in Android with outofmemory error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660823/upload-file-in-android-with-outofmemory-error)
    etc.....

I am uploading a video File which is inside file Manager /mfs_candidate_intro/65850.mp4

Now MainActivity.java

```
package com.servicedemo;

import java.io.File;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    private String fpath;
    private String myfile;
    private static final String UPLOAD_URL = "http://www.ourgoalplan.com/CandidateIntroUploader.ashx";
    private int candidateID =65850; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }


   public void startMethod(View v) {

       fpath=setVideoOutPutFile();
       Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Uploadservice.class);
        i.putExtra("filepath", fpath);
        i.putExtra("uploadurl", UPLOAD_URL);
        i.putExtra("candidateID", candidateID);
        startService(i);
}



   private String setVideoOutPutFile()
    {
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/mfs_candidate_intro");

        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists())
        {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs())
            {
                Log.d("VideoLogger", "failed to create directory");
            }
        }

        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        Log.e("external storagedirectory path= =", path);
        myfile = path + "/mfs_candidate_intro/" + candidateID + ".mp4";
        Log.e("external final file = =", myfile);
        return myfile;
    }



}
```

Uploadservice.java contains

```
package com.servicedemo;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Uploadservice extends IntentService{

    private String uploadURL;
    private int candidateID;
    private String FilePath;

    public Uploadservice() {      
        super("My service");

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
    }



    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {   //After completion of onstartcommand system will deliver all intent object to onHandleItent method.          

        uploadURL=intent.getExtras().getString("uploadurl");
        candidateID=intent.getExtras().getInt("candidateID");
        FilePath =intent.getExtras().getString("filepath");
        Log.d("Inside onhandleIntent", FilePath);
        try {
            uploadVideo(uploadURL,candidateID,FilePath);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }


    public byte[] filecovert(String path)
    {
        return null;

    }

    public void uploadVideo(String iUploadUrl, int iCandidateId, String iFilePath) throws IOException
    {
        /**
         * converts the file in the specified path to byte Array
         */
        byte[] videobytes = convertFileToBytes(iFilePath);


        // Number of chunks in Bytes..
        final long chunkSize = 100000;
        // creates a new file in the specified path..
        File videoFile = new File(iFilePath);



        if (videobytes != null && videobytes.length > 0)
        {


            String requestUri = iUploadUrl + "?CandidateID=" + iCandidateId + "&fileName=" + videoFile.getName();

            // get the number of chunks
            long numOfChunks = (videobytes.length / chunkSize);
            byte[] byteArray = new byte[(int) chunkSize];

            /**
             * Get the remaining Bytes. /Check if there is some bytes remaining after calculation of numOfChunks
             */
            long remaingbytes = videobytes.length % chunkSize;
            if (remaingbytes > 0)
            {
                // Increase number of chunks by one if some bytes are left ...
                numOfChunks = numOfChunks + 1;
            }
            long copyBytesLength = chunkSize;

            for (int chunkNo = 1; chunkNo <= numOfChunks; chunkNo++)
            {
                String requestURL = requestUri + "&TotalChunks=" + numOfChunks + "&ChunkCounter=" + chunkNo;
                copyBytesLength = ((chunkNo * chunkSize) > videobytes.length) ? remaingbytes : chunkSize;
                byteArray = new byte[(int) copyBytesLength];
                System.arraycopy(videobytes, (int) ((chunkNo - 1) * chunkSize), byteArray, 0, (int) copyBytesLength);

                // send request to Handler
                if (requestHandler(numOfChunks, byteArray, chunkNo, requestURL))
                {
                    Log.e("SplashScreen", "Request Handler Returns False " + iCandidateId);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method provides the file data as byte array
     * 
     * @param iFilePath
     *            the path to the file
     * @return the corresponding byte array representation
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private byte[] convertFileToBytes(String iFilePath) throws IOException
    {
        return FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(iFilePath));
    }

    /**
     * This method handles the division of byte array data into small chunks
     * 
     * @param iNumOfChunks
     *            number of chunks available after dividing data as separate 1 MB units
     * @param iByteArray
     *            the byte array representation of video data.
     * @param iChunkNum
     *            current chunk number
     * @param iRequestURL
     *            complete upload url
     * @return true/false based upon the success result.
     */
    private boolean requestHandler(long iNumOfChunks, byte[] iByteArray, int iChunkNum, String iRequestURL)
    {
        try
        {
            boolean valid = true;
            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            DataOutputStream dos = null;
            DataInputStream inStream = null;
            URL url = new URL(iRequestURL);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            // Writes iByteArray.length from IByteArray starting at offset 0 to the dos output stream.
            dos.write(iByteArray, 0, iByteArray.length);
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
            // get the response code returned by the HTTP server...
            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            Log.e("SplashScreen", "Response code is " + responseCode);
            /**
             * If response code is OK ,Check if the iChunkNum == iNumOfChunks If it is equal ,it means Writting to th
             */
            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            {
                if (iChunkNum == iNumOfChunks)
                {
                    inStream = new DataInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                    String str;
                    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
                    while ((str = inStream.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        buf.append(str);
                    }
                    str = buf.toString();
                    Log.e("SplashScreen", "Server Response" + str);
                    inStream.close();
                }
                else
                {
                    valid = false;
                }
            }
            return valid;
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

    }

 @Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.d("destroyed", "Intent destroyed");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "helloooooooooooo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    super.onDestroy();
}

}
```

Manifest.xml contains ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.servicedemo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

         <service
             android:name=".Myservice"
             android:exported="false"
        />

         <service
             android:name=".Uploadservice"
             android:exported="false"
        />

    </application>



</manifest>
```

My Problem is when file size is big it's showing

```
12-02 18:36:35.944: E/dalvikvm-heap(21228): Out of memory on a 90981622-byte allocation.
12-02 18:36:35.944: I/dalvikvm(21228): "IntentService[My service]" prio=5 tid=11 RUNNABLE
12-02 18:36:35.944: I/dalvikvm(21228):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x41bb0780 self=0x5832c038
12-02 18:36:35.944: I/dalvikvm(21228):   | sysTid=21405 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1479722576
12-02 18:36:35.944: I/dalvikvm(21228):   | schedstat=( 23006625 25262207 18 ) utm=2 stm=0 core=2
12-02 18:36:35.944: I/dalvikvm(21228):   at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(IOUtils.java:~512)
12-02 18:36:35.944: I/dalvikvm(21228):   at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(IOUtils.java:488)
12-02 18:36:35.944: I/dalvikvm(21228):   at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(FileUtils.java:1764)
12-02 18:36:35.944: I/dalvikvm(21228):   at com.servicedemo.Uploadservice.convertFileToBytes(Uploadservice.java:126)
12-02 18:36:35.944: I/dalvikvm(21228):   at com.servicedemo.Uploadservice.uploadVideo(Uploadservice.java:68)
12-02 18:36:35.944: I/dalvikvm(21228):   at com.servicedemo.Uploadservice.onHandleIntent(Uploadservice.java:47)
12-02 18:36:35.944: I/dalvikvm(21228):   at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
12-02 18:36:35.944: I/dalvikvm(21228):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-02 18:36:35.944: I/dalvikvm(21228):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-02 18:36:35.944: I/dalvikvm(21228):   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
12-02 18:36:35.949: W/dalvikvm(21228): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e962a0)
12-02 18:36:35.954: E/AndroidRuntime(21228): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[My service]
12-02 18:36:35.954: E/AndroidRuntime(21228): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
12-02 18:36:35.954: E/AndroidRuntime(21228):    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(IOUtils.java:512)
12-02 18:36:35.954: E/AndroidRuntime(21228):    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(IOUtils.java:488)
12-02 18:36:35.954: E/AndroidRuntime(21228):    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(FileUtils.java:1764)
12-02 18:36:35.954: E/AndroidRuntime(21228):    at com.servicedemo.Uploadservice.convertFileToBytes(Uploadservice.java:126)
12-02 18:36:35.954: E/AndroidRuntime(21228):    at com.servicedemo.Uploadservice.uploadVideo(Uploadservice.java:68)
12-02 18:36:35.954: E/AndroidRuntime(21228):    at com.servicedemo.Uploadservice.onHandleIntent(Uploadservice.java:47)
12-02 18:36:35.954: E/AndroidRuntime(21228):    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
12-02 18:36:35.954: E/AndroidRuntime(21228):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-02 18:36:35.954: E/AndroidRuntime(21228):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-02 18:36:35.954: E/AndroidRuntime(21228):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

The problem is inside

```
private byte[] convertFileToBytes(String iFilePath) throws IOException
    {
        return FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(iFilePath));
    }
```

it is defined in the Uploadservice.java

Also,Is it neccessary to use

```
String requestURL = requestUri + "&TotalChunks=" + numOfChunks + "&ChunkCounter=" + chunkNo;
```

or we can remove it???

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're reading the whole video into memory before uploading! This might be OK for an image file, but you can't assume that you have enough RAM to store a video while you upload it.

You need to open the file as an `InputStream`, and upload as you read from the stream.

You could also use a `MappedByteBuffer`. I'd go with a stream, but it does look as though a `MappedByteBuffer` would be closer to the code you already have.

Comment: i am new to android so i don't know how can i open the file as stream i am using only 
FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(iFilePath));    ....can you tell me how to open it as stream and then convert it as Byte Array ..as i am returning only byte array from the function ..thnx in advance.. :)

Comment: @RajeevKumar look up `FileInputStream`. But the whole point is **to avoid** converting it to a byte array. You need a small buffer, and as you read from the stream into the buffer, you upload from there (inside a loop, until the stream is finished).

Comment: please correct me if i am wrong .. At first i am converting the video file into byte array then ,dividing it into no. of chunks and for each chunk,i am setting url and then calling a function(requestHandler)which opens connection and upload the chunk ....My Question is how will i divide video into number of chunks if i use stream ????Also ,URL using &TotalChunks and &ChunkCounter to open connection ..so can't avoid dividing video into number of chunks.. ....Please provide a link if you have so..